# What is the ApplicatinTest class in newer android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In older version of the **Android Studio** was not the `ApplicationTest` class in the new default project. But when I create the new default project in android studio 1.3, I have two classes:

**1-** `MainActivity`class.

**2-**`ApplicationTest` class.

I know what it is the `MainActivity` class but I do not know what is it the `ApplicationTest` class. Can I remove the `ApplicationTest`class from my project?  Do I allow to remove the `ApplicatioTest` class from my project? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I do not know what is it the ApplicationTest class ?

Its class for Unit testing provided by android studio.

> Can I remove the ApplicationTestclass from my project?

You can remove ApplicationTest class from application

> Do I allow to remove the ApplicatioTest class from my project?

Yes you can remove